# How to obtain Full Size Profile Picture of facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

How to obtain a full size profile picture from Facebook ?

http://graph.facebook.com/{ID}/picture?type=large is way to small. I want a bigger size ? Is that possible ?  I need a way without FBML because that is soon to end

Answer (score 1):

You can specify `width` and/or `height` and Facebook will return an image less than or equal to the given size.

`http://graph.facebook.com/{ID}/picture?width={size_in_pixels}&redirect=false`

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass another variable `"redirect=true"` in the url. That means, your URL will be like `http://graph.facebook.com/{ID}/picture?type=large&redirect=true`

Answer (score -1):

If you have user_photos permission you should be able to get the current profile picture by finding the first image in the Profile Pictures Album.  Here is some [sample code](http://kilianvalkhof.com/2011/javascript/full-size-profile-picture-via-the-facebook-javascript-sdk/) from Kilian Valkhof.