# How to get Facebook images in which my friend is tagged

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I am developing a web application using Java. I need to access my friends photos and need to select the photo in which he is tagged. ( i.e ) His face should be there in that photo.

How to do it with Facebook Api's? I have searched and got few SO posts for taking profile picture of friends like this [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312543/getting-facebook-profile-picture) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498103/how-to-obtain-full-size-profile-picture-of-facebook), but I couldn't get anything related to accessing friends photos and getting their images in which they are tagged/ friends face is available.

Can someone help me out on how to accomplish the above case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo_tag/

To get links you have to run query like

```
select link from photo where object_id in 
    (select object_id from photo_tag where subject=me())
```

Of courset instead of `me()` you have to write your friend id.

Note, that

```
To read the photo_tag table you need the following permissions:
User:
user_photos permissions to access photo tag information that a user is tagged in.
friends_photos permissions to access photo tag information that a friend is tagged in.
```

BTW you will receive photos on which the person is tagged, but these photos may contain no real image of person.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The query you have mentioned is not working. I am getting {
  "data": [
  ]
} as output.

Comment: You have [] even if you provide subject=me()?

Comment: Yes I am getting the same even if I provide subject=me()

Comment: Can you test the query from your end?

Comment: yes, this query (in answer above) lists all links on photos I was tagged in. But it does not return photos where it is said "with XXX", only those where my face (or a point that pretends to be my face) is present

Comment: Is the given format wrong in the answer above? I have checked in two different accounts.

Comment: It worked for me actually. Does this query `select object_id from photo_tag where subject=me()` work for you? If no, then user you're logged in under is not tagged anywhere. If you tag yourself somewhere will this query work?

Comment: No this query is not working for me.. **select object_id from photo_tag where subject=me()** I have checked in my friends account also, it is not working..

Comment: Do you run this query from FQL explorer? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?fql=select%20object_id%20from%20photo_tag%20where%20subject%3Dme()

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I havent turned on the access tokens. Its working now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience.And Can I get another query to access my friends photo album?

Comment: It should be like `select object_id from photo_tag where subject in (select uid1 from friend where uid2=me() )`, but you need permissions to receive results, otherwise you'll receive empty data[] array.